# Getting json response but not able to parse in to label

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am getting response in json format and i have array in to array but I am not able to under stood how to print on label i saw my code here

I am getting response of business_time array value so can any one please help

```
    func CallAPI() {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

        let uid = "u_id"
        let acctkn = "acc_tkn"


        if preferences.object(forKey: uid) == nil {
            //  Doesn't exist
        } else {
            let u_id = preferences.object(forKey: uid) as! String
            print(u_id)
            let acc_tkn = preferences.object(forKey: acctkn) as! String
            print(acc_tkn)

            let userprofile = ["user_id":u_id,"access_token":acc_tkn]
            SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")
            Alamofire.request(businessDetailByUserId, method: .post, parameters: userprofile).responseJSON
                {
                    response in
                    //printing response
                    print(response)
                    let result = response.result.value
                    // let obj=result


                    if result != nil{
                        let data = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                        let userdata = data["data"] as! NSDictionary
                        let userTimings = userdata["business_time"]
                        print(userTimings)
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my response::

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": {
        "bus_usr_id": "12",
        "fk_user_id": "88",
        "fk_cate_id": "2",
        "bus_name": "AutoMobiles",
        "bus_logo": "https://www.kwikmypay.com/mode_share/modeshare_admin/assets/images/business/bus_uvbdt1531395509.png",
        "bus_address": "404 Palladium",
        "bus_email": "mihir@hemshub.com",
        "bus_website": "www.hemshub.com",
        "bus_desc": "All types of automobiles spare parts are available.",
        "fav_status": 1,
        "bus_contact_no": "9876543210",
        "bus_status": "1",
        "sub_cate_list": "Spare Parts",
        "category": "Automobiles",
        "business_time": [
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "107",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Monday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "108",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Tuesday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "109",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Wednesday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "110",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Thursday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:7",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "111",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Friday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:8",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "112",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Saturday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:8",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            },
            {
                "tbl_bus_time_id": "113",
                "fk_user_id": "88",
                "fk_bus_id": "12",
                "day": "Sunday",
                "start_time": "17:7",
                "end_time": "23:8",
                "status": "1",
                "created_date": "2018-07-12 11:38:29"
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": ""
```

i want to print values of business_time array on label but i am new to swift so can any one please tell me how to print

Comment: There are so many values in business_time, how many values do you want to print and in which format and how will it look in the UI?

Comment: i want to print start time and end time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
    let userdata = jsonData["data"] as? [String: Any]
    let businessJsonArray = userdata["business_time"] as? [[String: Any]] {

    for businessJson in businessJsonArray {
         let id = businessJson["tbl_bus_time_id"]
    }               
 }
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Above pattern is old. Apple release `JsonEndcoder()` in swift 4 which you should try.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the value for key `business_time` is an array so you get multiple items.

Basically don't use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` in Swift, you throw away the important type information and a JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is always `[String:Any]`, never `[String:AnyObject]`

```
//printing response
print(response)
//don't check for `nil`, use optional bindings for all objects
if let result = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
   let userdata = result["data"] as? [String : Any],
   let userTimings = userdata["business_time"] as? [[String : Any]] {
       for timing in userTimings {
           print(timing["start_time"] as! String)
           print(timing["end_time"] as! String)

       }

}
SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in each JSON there is response sector responsible for server status (200 = success etc).
Next part is data... so basically, you have several important dictionaries (header, data). To output data without alamofire:

Write to me the response.

```
func CallAPI()
{
        let url = URL(string: "https:// your_Address")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let _ = response, let data = data
            {
                    let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                    print(result as NSString)

            } else {
                print(error as Any)
            }
        }

            task.resume()
    }
```